# Getting different format of date while conversion in java

Tags: java

A very good morning  , I have just one query, below is the program which upon execution the year gets changed. Lets say the date as input is `03/20/2020` then the date upon execution, the program comes as `03/08/2021` which is totally wrong. As the year is incremented  and the complete date is wrong.
Please advise how can i correct my program to achieve the same date.

```
public class DateFormattingTest {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.println ("03/20/2020:" + extractDate("03/20/2020") );


        DateFormattingTest test = new DateFormattingTest();
        convertDate(test, "03/20/2020");

    }

    public static Date extractDate(String dateStr) {

        String [] datePatterns = {"yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy","MM/dd/yyyy" };
        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateStr, datePatterns);
        }
        catch (Exception except) {
                except.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }


    private static void convertDate(DateFormattingTest test, String dateString) {
        java.util.Date date = test.convertStringToDate(dateString);
        System.out.println(dateString + " -> " + outputDate.format(date));
    }

    public java.util.Date convertStringToDate(String stringValue) {
        String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yy", "dd-MM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" };

        for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
            try {
                java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString)
                        .parse(stringValue);
                return date;
            } catch (ParseException e) {

            }
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: Your original `String` date seems to be in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy`, which `extractDate` uses, but your `convertStringToDate` is using the `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Comment: shall i add MM/dd/yyyy also in the array

Comment: That would be a good start

Comment: after adding that still the output is 03/20/2020 -> 03/08/2021

Comment: I'm assuming you added it to the end of the `formatStrings` array?  Which means that `dd/MM/yyyy` is been evaluated before `MM/dd/yyyy`, resulting in the wrong conversion, see my answer (I only have a vague notion of why it's happening, I just know it does)

Answer (score 2):

Your original `String` date seems to be in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy`, which `extractDate` uses, but your `convertStringToDate` is using the `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

`SimpleDateFormat` is using the pattern `dd/MM/yyyy` to parse the `stringValue` which is actually in `MM/dd/yyyy`, because the formatter can't determine which values represent what, it assumes and corrects for the month been `20`, but rolling the year.

A simple check against this is to compare the resulting `Date` with the `String` by formatting the `Date` with the original formatter, for example...

```
public java.util.Date convertStringToDate(String stringValue) {
    String[] formatStrings = {"dd/MM/yy", "dd-MM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy"};

    for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
            java.util.Date date = df.parse(stringValue);

            if (df.format(date).equals(stringValue)) {
                System.out.println(formatString + "; " + stringValue + "; " + date);
                return date;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

Which now returns `null`.

However, if I add `MM/dd/yyyy` to the `formatStrings` (`String[] formatStrings = {"dd/MM/yy", "dd-MM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy"};`) in the `convertStringToDate` method, it will return `20/03/2020`

Comment: nice explanation, but I have one query about how SimpeDateFormat behave for different date patterns, could you please explain it more @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You may want to checkout the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html))

The original java date and time utilities suffer a number of deficiencies making them prone to programmer error.

java.time has [immutable objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and other thoughtful design. It's the new de-facto standard.

For example:

```
String date_string = "03/20/2020";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(date_string, formatter);
```

wouldn't silently fail. Instead, it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03/20/2020' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 20
```

and the debugging would likely have gone much more quickly...

Comment: @BasilBourque Valid point. I built out the answer a bit more.